# Problem with Bash's command_not_found_handle()

Tags: macos, bash

I get "command not found" error in Mac by the following command

```
md5sum *.java | uniq -d -w32
```

The reason is that Mac does not have -w option by default.

I would like to make Bash to do the following when the error occurs

1. put g at the beginning of the first command
2. put g at the beginning of a command which is after |

How can you make the error more useful?

**[edit]**

Problem: if Mac does not have the feature, I want use the features in coreutils. Therefore, the g in front of Mac's commands.

Comment: what do you mean by "does not have -w option by default"

Comment: You need to install coreutils to get Unix commands. Then, you can run GNU's commnands by putting g in front of any Mac's commands.

Comment: Will it be ok just to put 'g' before even first running?

Comment: @Mykola: It will not be ok. In some cases, Mac's commands are better than those in Coreutils. The reverse is true too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You cannot use `command_not_found_handle()`** because the commands *do* exist; they just return an error (`$? != 0`) because of unrecognized parameters.

In these kinds of situations you should explicitly control the commands issued with **a platform-specific prologue** at the very beginning of the script, making the minimum number of assumptions about parameters, e.g.:

```
# defaults - satisfies most platforms
MD5SUM=md5sum
UNIQ=uniq
# per-platform exceptions
if [ "$OS" == "MacOS" ] ; then
  # use GNU variants by prefixing with g
  MD5SUM="g $MD5SUM"  # or use the native program, MD5SUM=md5
  UNIQ="g $UNIQ"      # or use the native program, UNIQ=uniq
elif [ "$OS" == "SomeOtherOS" ] ; then
  MD5SUM=md5hash # e.g. this platform computes MD5 sums with md5hash
fi
...
# optionally cross-check for GNU variants on all platforms
#  does uniq support -w32? (no error on dry run?) if so, use it!
$UNIQ -w32 /dev/null 2>/dev/null && UNIQ="$UNIQ -w32"
# optionally perform one last validation before proceeding
die() { echo "FATAL: $*" >&2 ; exit $1 ; }
$UNIQ /dev/null >/dev/null   || die $? "uniq is missing or failing: $UNIQ"
$MD5SUM /dev/null >/dev/null || die $? "md5sum is missing or failing: $MD5SUM"
...
$MD5SUM *.java | $UNIQ -d
```

---

**UPDATE**

Note that it is also good practice, especially if your script will run as `root`, to *not* rely on `$PATH` -- you would want to specify the fully qualified locations for programs such as `uniq` or `md5` or `md5sum` above, e.g. `UNIQ=/bin/uniq`, `MD5SUM=/sbin/md5sum`, etc.)

---

**UPDATE2**

To automatically prefix a bunch of commands with "g":

```
eval `for command in uniq md5sum grep sed ; do
  echo \`echo \$command | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'\`=\"g \$command\"
done`
```

Comment: It seems that I have write the above code for each Unix command. What is the fast way to do that?

Comment: you don't have to do this for each command, only for the problematic ones.  But if you really must:   eval `for command in uniq md5sum grep sed ; do echo \`echo \$command | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'\`=\"g \$command\" ; done`

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X works:

/sbin/md5 *.java | uniq -d

For gnu uniq see:

http://rudix.org/#coreutils

Comment: And the -w32 option for uniq isn't needed, too, because the macos md5 uses a different output format than the "real" md5sum. :-)